# Get value where variable name stored in another variable

Tags: javascript, eval

Without using eval ... I'm trying to see if I can get a value from a variable where the value is stored in another variable. Such as get value of 'ValueC' from varA where varA='varB' and varB='ValueC'

The user will enter a string, simulated below as the variable named 'UserSpecified'.  They could enter any character and if doesn't match an existing variable ... well I'll just return null.

I realize I can do this with an eval(), but evals seem to be frowned upon I'm trying to do it in a better way.

I've tried the ES2015+ accepted answer from ["Variable" variables in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187530/variable-variables-in-javascript) but I'm not having any success.  Am I missing something or should I stick with an eval?

```js
let a  = "aye";
let b = "be";
let c = "sea";

let userSpecified="a";
let obj = {userSpecified};
let parm='userSpecified';

console.log(eval(userSpecified));  // This displays 'aye'

console.log(obj[parm]); // This displays 'a' but I would like it to display 'aye'
```

Comment: Why should it output `aye` when `obj` is `{ "userSpecified": "a" }`?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you wanted to do but try: `let userSpecified={a};` it should output both 'aye' as object of course.

Comment: Good question, sorry I should have explained that a bit.  The user will enter a value in an edit field so I was trying to convey that with the variable named 'UserSpecified'  but I obviously didn't do that well.   I'm going to edit my question to clarify that point.

Comment: This still doesn't make much sense... Why `obj`? `window[userSpecified] === "aye" // if userspecified === "a"`

Comment: Because @DBTake3 is still expecting that value to be the name of a local variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can restructure your code so that an object holds the values, then it's just basic **obj.key = val** syntax (**exactly: obj[key] = val**).

```js
const obj = {
  a: "aye",
  b: "be",
  c: "sea"
}

const userSpecified = "a";

console.log(obj[userSpecified]); // expected: aye
```

If not, then use **var** instead of **let**:

```js
// pay attention that it's var not let
var a = "aye";

let userSpecified = "a";

console.log(window[userSpecified]) // expected: aye
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped.

Comment: I’m happy that I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get the value of a local variable dynamically (aside from `eval`).

But you can use an object to store data (not the names of local variables), and access that data with dynamic keys.

I think this is what you want:

```
const data = {
  a: "1",
  b: "2",
  c: "3",
}

// Take the name of an object property and return its corresponding value.
function getValue(userSpecified) {
  return data[userSpecified]
}

console.log(getValue("a")) // 1
console.log(getValue("b")) // 2

console.log(getValue(someFormField.value))
```

Comment: Thanks!  This helped